# How did Flash take care of the bomb?

Tags: dc, the-flash, dc-animated-movie-universe, flashpoint-paradox

In the DC Animated Original Movie *Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox*, The Flash needs to dispose of a bomb early in the film.  He accomplishes this by vibrating his hand and then hurling *something* from that hand.  That something hits the bomb, breaking it.  The dialogue during this indicates this is some clever use of his super speed powers, but I'm unclear on what specifically he did here.

What did the Flash do when he vibrated his hand?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was a spherical vacuum that Barry somehow "threw" at Zoom. Was that just me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that he utilized the Speed Force (since Batman mentioned the costume is supposed to reduce friction) and its ability to grant him control over kinetic energy (and even his own molecular structure) to generate a mass of static electricity, possibly ball lightning, that allowed him to short the bombs circuitry before it exploded. This is why Hence Flash stated "I guess 25th Century technology is pretty delicate".

When you see the resultant animation you notice the bomb looks like it is shorting out rather than being physically damaged.  Professor Zoom also stated earlier that physical agitation (just trying to remove their belts) would cause the device to go off - so there has to be another process other than physical force.

Answer (score 4):

A recent addition to the Flash's powers has been the ability to transfer vibration or "Speed Force" energy from one object to another. This corresponding transfer brings a certain amount of kinetic energy with it. He has the ability to subtract energy from objects as well.

- Think of it like a bullet without the need for the corresponding gunpowder charge needed to propel the object. Depending on his level of control, the object would not need to be very large, only large enough to transfer the energy. At the right velocity, even a tiny object can transfer an incredible amount of energy with it (think micro-meteorite).
- If his vibrational control was precise enough, he could simply cause the thrown object to pass through the outer shell of the bomb and reappear (stop vibrating) disrupting the bomb process by suddenly appearing within the mechanism of the bomb, stopping it.
- If he didn't throw anything, perhaps it is just the ability to direct his vibrational control power AT RANGE. Normally the Flash's powers were limited to things he could touch (given his incredible speed, few things were out of his range for very long) so this would be an unusual use (i.e. new use) of his vibration powers.

Comment: While your answer makes sense, to me it looks like he's created a small "ball" of compressed air by moving his palm rapidly. I'm not sure if that's scientifically possible, so I'm leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Compressed air would technically count as "matter" albeit, this would require incredible power to compress, contain, and control air molecules to be used as a weapon. This would count as an "incredible Flash feat."

Comment: @Thaddeus That's easy, Bartholomew did it in One Piece ! Oops, if you're looking for me, I'm already out...